# View Taxonomy Term List with Exposed Has taxonomy terms (with depth) filter

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have view list of terms of a vocabulary. The terms of it have an entity reference field of another vocabulary (with hierarchically organized terms).

I would like to filter the terms by that entity reference like I am used to do with nodes with a "Has taxonomy terms (with depth)" filter.

Does a depth filter really only work with nodes?

Kind regards and thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a issue as you ask the question.

The current answer is that Drupal 8 does not yet support this feature besides node content type.

I'm also following this issue.

more details at:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2915933

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1040786

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links.